# Why PHP does not have a function to redirect page at any given instant?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm aware that you can use the `header('Location: next.php')` to accomplish that as well as other possible solutions, but that must be used before any output is sent to the client. My question is why PHP doesn't support a function to page redirection at any given time. I just want to know **why**, not interested in solutions or workarounds. Thanks.

Comment: you can use header() anytime you want, as long as no output has been performed. if you need to do header() calls at arbitrary points, then use ob_start() and off you go.

Comment: Why does this not fit for Q&A format? Alhough the question is not based on practical matters or "facts" I think it could be answered pretty straightforward.

Comment: consider SO like a courtroom. you're asking for opinion. "I think that guy did it" "Good enough for me, guilty, off with his head" kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that `PHP` is a ***server side*** language. Therefore, once the page is loaded on the client's browser, you no longer have control or access to it. It would not be possible to manipulate the loading, reloading, or relocation of the client's browser window after the content has left the server.

Comment: -1 TS is not trying to magically issue PHP commands while the browser is looking at the page, he is working out why he can't force redirects at arbitrary points during PHP's rendering process.

Comment: @Niels Per the OP's question "My question is why PHP doesn't support a function to page redirection at any given time..." The statement is slighty vague and only leads to discussion (hints while it is now closed). ***Define*** any given time? You're assuming the OP is referring to _PHP's rendering process_. However the statement is vague. Any given time could mean, during the rendering, after the rendering, next year, etc. I think it is a fallacy to assume this. The simple and clear answer is that once the content is output to the client, PHP loses control of the data. Plain and simple.

Comment: Well, given that your answer is accepted your interpretation is apparently right, but the multiple possible interpretations make the closing as a whole all the more required.

Comment: PHP could be default have output buffering on. It's just a design decision. Then as long as the script is not done you could change headers. So this doesn't really say why. The real reason is- they decided to make it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's really a client side function. That's why you use `HTML` to accomplish this.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.google.com">
```

Comment: Who uses HTML to do a **server** side redirect?

Comment: @DiegoAgulló You don't need to be using `PHP` to accomplish this.

Comment: @DiegoAgulló who said anything about it being a server side redirect? The OP simply asked about a redirect.

Comment: Further, you can accomplish it using JavaScript.

Comment: -1 This answer does not in any way answer the question, it just provides a flawed alternative and ignores the explicitly requested **why** of the problem. TS even explicitly states he doesn't need workarounds or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so everything is preprocessed on the server before being displayed on the client... Therefore any PHP redirects should happen before anything is sent to the client... redirects that need to be done after the page is loaded have to happen with client side JS or meta refresh code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because the function you quoted uses the HTTP headers to send the redirect.

HTTP headers must be (as the name implies) sent at the start of the response, before any actual content.

As soon as you've sent any content, you can no longer send any HTTP headers. That's why it doesn't work.

It is possible to set PHP not to send any content by using the `ob_start()` function. If you do that, you *will* be able to send the redirect after generating output. This works because the HTTP content is not sent using this method, and therefore it is still valid to send HTTP headers.

However under normal circumstances, sending any body content means that you cannot send any subsequent headers.

There are other Javascript methods to trigger a redirect which can be done in the page body content, but these work entirely differently and are not available as a standard PHP function. It's easy enough to call them though by sending the relevant javascript code as part of your HTTP content output.

Answer (score 0):

It's because to do an HTTP redirect, the redirect must be in the response header.  The headers come before the content body.  Once any of the body is output, you cannot send a header.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot send headers after you started sending the body.

1. HTTP header
2. HTTP body

that's it. PHP starts sending the response (i.e. header and part of the body) as soon as your script outputs anything. So it is not possible to add a redirection header at *any* given time in code.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTP does not support it.

The HTTP protocol essentially splits a response in 3 parts:

1. A numeric code and description describing the result of the request (ie. `200 OK`)
2. The headers describing what it is going to send
3. The content of the response

PHP considers 1 and 2 both headers, but HTTP simply cannot add new headers after it has started flushing out content (step 3). As such, you have to specify redirections before sending content, because it means the response code will be changed to a number in the 3xx range, and a `Location` header added.

You can, to a certain extent, alleviate this behaviour by forcing PHP not to send content right away when it's generated, by using *output buffering*:

```
ob_start();
```

After this call all output is buffered until you explicitly flush it or the script ends, allowing you to still change headers. It's bad practice to use it for this though, it's far better to determine the result of a request before you start rendering output.

Answer (score -1):

1. Enable output_buffering in php.ini- then you can use Location: anywhere you want
2. Use a framework- they usually have a function for it
3. Use buffering "manually": ob_start(); ob_get_contents(), etc.
   Then you can use redirects ANYWHERE in code

There is also JS solution you can use:

```
<script>location.href="/";</script>
```

Or even meta-redirect in HTML. Just output that HTML/JS code with PHP and it will do a redirect.

Comment: "I just want to know why, not interested in solutions or workarounds."

Comment: @GeorgeCummins The real reason is like: "They decided to make it work like that". Output buffering could be a a thing enabled by default. The question asked is also: "My question is why PHP doesn't support a function to page redirection at any given time." My answer is: it *does* so the "why" makes no sense here.